# AWS Cloudwatch metrics log - view log from graph

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

When viewing graphed Cloudwatch metric, how can one see which log/event is showed on graph without filtering the log stream for time showed on graph?

For example: on graph I can see one lambda error occurred at 12:21 pm, but I can't see the specific event.